# Minimal polynomial of $\theta^2$

Tags: galois-theory

I'm doing this Galois Theory question:

$f = x^3 + x + 3$ is known to be irreducible and has just one real root, call it $\theta$.

What is the minimal polynomial for $\theta^2$? Is it just $f$?

Comment: There is a standard trick here. The polynomial $f(x)f(-x)$ is even. Therefore we can write
$$g(x^2)=-f(x)f(-x)$$ for some monic polynomial $g(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ of degree three. It follows that $g(\theta^2)=0$. This is also a duplicate. Gimme a minute.

Comment: If $\theta$ is real, then so is $\theta^2$. But $f$ has only one real root. Can the required minimal polynomial be $f$?

Comment: Good point @Git Gud

Comment: The method is described with a quartic example [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/610813/11619). I have seen more recent incarnations of it here, but my search-fu is weak today :-(

Comment: The trick plays a role in [Graeffe's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeffe's_method).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $\theta^2$ must have degree at most $3$.

So, we need to look for a linear equation for $1, \theta^2, \theta^4, \theta^6$.

$\theta^3 = -\theta-3$ implies $\theta^4= -\theta^2-3\theta$ and $\theta^6= \theta^2+6\theta+9$. So $\theta^6+2\theta^4=-\theta^2+9$.

A systematic way of refining this relation is to solve a linear system $Ax=0$, where the columns of $A$ are the coordinates of $1, \theta^2, \theta^4, \theta^6$ in the basis $1, \theta, \theta^2$.

Comment: I was trying something like this but it just wouldn't work! Thanks a lot for that, I like your method.

Answer (score 2):

There’s another systematic way of doing this, involving the Norm. Let $R=\Bbb Q[X]$, and look at $S=R[\theta]/(\theta^3+\theta+3)$, and the Norm from $S$ down to $R$. You can calculate the Norm of an element $z$ by looking at the $R$-linear map $w\mapsto zw$, and calculating its determinant. It’s just a $3\times3$ with coefficients in $R$, not bad at all to do.

But the Norm of $X-\theta^2$ is clearly a cubic polynomial in $R=\Bbb Q[X]$ that has $\theta^2$ for a root. In this case, it is irreducible, and the computation gives $-9 + X + 2X^2 + X^3$.